# Spring: Use different service depending on if the method is triggered from a schedule or not

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot Application and an interface `GraphService` which implements some default methods and defines one method `getGraphClient()`:

```
interface GraphService {
    fun getGraphClient(): GraphServiceClient<Request>

    fun getAllUsers(): List<User> {
        // ... using getGraphClient()
    }

    // ...
}
```

Two services, a `GraphUserService` and an `GraphApplicationService` implement this interface and in particular the method `getGraphClient()`:

```
@Service
class GraphUserService() {

    override fun getGraphClient(): GraphServiceClient<Request> {
        // build graph client for user requests
    }

}
```

.

```
@Service
class GraphApplicationService() {

    override fun getGraphClient(): GraphServiceClient<Request> {
        // build graph client for application requests
    }

}
```

Now I have a method `refreshUsers()` in an `AdminService` which is triggered automatically and regularly by a schedule:

```
@Service
class ScheduleService(
    private val adminService: AdminService
) {

    @Scheduled(cron = "@monthly")
    fun executeMonthlySchedule() {
        adminService.refreshUsers()
    }

}
```

Additionally, the method `refreshUsers()` can be triggered proactive by an user.

**My aim:** `refreshUsers()` should use the `getAllUsers()` method from the `GraphUserService` if its triggered by an user and the `getAllUsers()` method from the `GraphApplicationService` if its triggered by the automatic schedule.

How can I reach this? I thought of conditional beans but didn't come to a result until now.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are two important issues to solve.
The language I used is Java, but I don't think Kotlin will be any different.

- Dynamic dependency injection for beans that implement the same interface

  - This problem can be solved by using dynamic dependency injection using Map.
- **How ​​to distinguish between user requests and scheduler?**

  - A simple way that comes to mind is to plant a Flag in the user request, but @Scheduled annotated methods cannot have parameters.
- then?

  - Wouldn’t it be possible to distinguish it by importing the path metadata that called the method?
  - If it is a request from the user, we will usually call a submethod in the Controller class.
  - For scheduling, no method is called in the Controller.
- My solution is to use StackTrace.
- Verification method

  - Implemented a method to distinguish between methods of beans that implement the same interface.
  - In some cases, dependency injection will be done dynamically, so if a different output appears, verification is successful.

  ```java
  @Service
  @RequiredArgsConstructor
  public class ScheduleService {

      private final AdminService adminService;

      @Scheduled(cron = "0/1 * * * * ?")
      public void executeMonthlySchedule() {
          adminService.refreshUsers();
      }
  }
  ```

  ```java
  @Service
  public class GraphUserService implements GraphService {

      @Override
      public void getAllUsers() {
          System.out.println("GraphUserService.getAllUsers");
      }
  }
  ```

  ```java
  @Service
  public class GraphApplicationService implements GraphService {
      @Override
      public void getAllUsers() {
          System.out.println("GraphApplicationService.getAllUsers");
      }
  }
  ```

  ```java
  @Slf4j
  @Service
  @RequiredArgsConstructor
  public class AdminService {

      private final Map<String, GraphService> graphServiceMap;

      public void refreshUsers() {
          StackTraceElement[] ste = new Throwable().getStackTrace();
          String methodCallClassName = ste[2].getClassName();
          log.info("methodCallClassName={}", methodCallClassName);
          //if method call class name contain upper class name -> DI graphUserService
          GraphService graphService;
          if (methodCallClassName.contains("Controller")) {
              graphService = graphServiceMap.get("graphUserService");
          } else {
              graphService = graphServiceMap.get("graphApplicationService");
          }
          graphService.getAllUsers();
      }
  }

  /*
  methodCallClassName=example.controller.AdminController
  GraphUserService.getAllUsers
  */

  /*
  methodCallClassName=jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor
  GraphApplicationService.getAllUsers
  */
  ```
- Dynamic injection of dependencies was solved by using Map.

  - There is also a way to use annotations, but I prefer this method because it is quite intuitive.
- Check the elements of StackTraceElement.

  - I was able to check the path of the parent class that was the caller in ste[2].
  - Depending on the coding, the index of this part may be at 0 or 1.
  - There is a risk in using magic numbers, but the problem can be solved.
- Checked the AdminController path to verify that it calls graphUserService in that case.
- @Scheduled calls also work as expected.

There may be better ideas, but I hope my ideas are helpful.